# How to use the ORM when multiple sqlite 'documents' can be opened

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, pyqt

In an application that uses sqlite files as documents in a new, open, save, and close type fashion what would be the appropriate way to configure the engines so that I could use the ORM?

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import *
from sqlalchemy import schema, create_engine, Table, Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker, mapper


class User(object):
    def __init__(self, name=None, email=None):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % (self.name)


class Document(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.database = Database()
        self.database.init_db()

    def close(self):
        self.database.session.remove()


class Database(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=False)
        self.metadata = schema.MetaData()
        self.session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=self.engine))
        self.tables = {}

        users = Table('users', self.metadata,
            Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
            Column('name', String(50), unique=True),
            Column('email', String(120), unique=True)
        )
        self.tables['users'] = users
        # mapper(User, users)

    def init_db(self):
        self.metadata.create_all(bind=self.engine)


document1 = Document()
document2 = Document()

document1.close()
document2.close()
```

I can easily use the regular sql commands such as

```
ins = database1.tables['users'].insert(
    values = dict(name=u'Test User', email=u'user@localhost')
)
result = database1.session.execute(ins)

s = select([database1.tables['users']])
result = database1.session.execute(s)
for row in result:
    print row
```

But I would like to be able to use the full orm capabilities of sqlalchemy. The problem I'm running into is that when one document is created that session is mapped to the User object preventing any further documents from being created.

Thanks

Comment: I do not understand your reasoning. But for a solution, just move the definition of the `User` class inside the `Database.__init__`, in which case these will be different classes. You will have to query then like `select(documentX.database.User)`..